# Neo4j 2.0 How Long can a Cypher Query Be when Passed to the Execution Engine?

Tags: plugins, cypher, neo4j

Basically, what's the limit on query size?

I'm writing a query that searches all properties in the database for a string. At the end of the query, I take the results and sort them into buckets.  This makes for a very long cypher query.

I'm passing this query to the Execution Engine in a server plug-in.  Right now I have a limited amount of properties, so the query runs fine.  I'm just concerned that as I get more properties over time that the actual string size of the query will be too long for the execution engine.

I've got a query that basically has a ton of lines like this:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE
( n:Program__CMC ) or    
n.learningObjective =~ '(?i).*criteria.*' or  
n.behavior =~ '(?i).*criteria.*' 

// This places the results into categories
WITH n  RETURN 
SUM(CASE when any(l IN labels(n) WHERE l='Program__CMC') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LABELProgram__CMC ,  
SUM(CASE WHEN  n.acronymn =~ '(?i).*criteria.*'  THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) AS NODEacronymn, SUM(CASE WHEN  n.behavior =~ '(?i).*criteria.*'  THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) AS NODEbehavior
```

This is just a very small subset of the query I'm running.  I'm actually using parameters and searching on labels and relationships as well, but I left those out for clarity.

If there's a limit, and there's a possibility I'll reach it, then I'll have to split up the query and merge the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no stated limit, although I've seen some interesting problems when you get into the several megabyte range, so it's not unlimited. I'm more worried that you're going to need to hit every node in the database for this query--is there no label you can filter on in the MATCH, at least?

Comment: Thanks Wes.  My query will not be in the megabyte range.  I do have a number of labels I'll be using to filter on the match clause.  That's one of the reasons I was wondering about the query size - If I add a "n:label AND n.property = criteria" clause for every group of properties, then I'm going get a much longer query.